# How to make plots larger in GnuPlot

Tags: gnuplot

I am generating mapped 3D plots using the following config file (`XRANGE` and `YRANGE` are set later)

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot    
reset
set term postscript eps enhanced

set size square
set xlabel "X position"
set ylabel "Y position"

#Have a gradient of colors from blue (low) to red (high)
set pm3d map
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31

set xrange [0 : XRANGE]
set yrange [0 : YRANGE]

set style line 1 lw 1

unset key

set dgrid3d 45,45

set hidden3d

splot "data.data" u 1:2:3
```

The resulting image looks something like this

[image: GnuPlot Image]

Note: I have converted to `jpg` so the quality is lower, and I have placed a border around the image.

A great deal of space is wasted above and below. This is not a problem until I embed the image into a LaTex document, at which point it will look like so (again, `pdf` document converted to `jpg` image)

[image]

The image on the right is also created with GnuPlot, but it is slightly larger (as is evident by looking at the border I have drawn around the top two images). The reason for this is because GnuPlot pads the 3D plot with top and bottom white space. How can I remove this without having to manually edit all 50+ plots I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also crop the Bounding Box afterwards, since I hate playing around with margins in gnuplot. I realized that somehow, eps2eps indeed does adjust the bounding box, but it also transforms text (labels etc) into pixel-graphic?!

I usually  use "epstool" which conserves text as text when croping the bb, the command I use is:

epstool --copy --bbox in.eps out.eps

Comment: Gnuplot has some of the worst documentation around. The sad thing is that there are very few alternatives. Although `eps2eps` gets rid of the margin, it doesn't solve the underlying problem: for some reason gnuplot plots 3D graphs slightly smaller than 2D graphs. Even if you tweaked the font so when stretched to the same size in LaTex, you then have to deal with the fact that Latex subfigures can not be spaced apart, so you now have two graphs smushed together.

Comment: @puk Well, feel free to suggest improvements to the documentation.

Comment: This works very well instead of this originally I convert eps to pdf then use `pdfcrop` command but this is better.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions to this, one is unreliable, the other is a hack.

1. Using GnuPlot, the [margin settings](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot1-e.html) can be used to specify distances from the appropriate margins. For example, setting `lmargin 0` and `bmargin 0` essentially pushes the axes off the page. Similar values can be assigned to the `tmargin` and `rmargin` to stretch the graph. Although this worked for 2D graphs, it did not work for 3D graphs (I suspect this has to do with the fact that I set the graph to be a square).
2. When graphs are set to be of square size, Gnuplot [still calculates for the entire screen](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/postscript-e.html). The eps file can be manipulated directly to change this by looking for a line like so `%%BoundingBox: 50 50 410 302` and changing `410` to something smaller. Alternatively, and this is what I did, you can run `eps2eps in.eps out.eps` and it will crop it for you. Just make sure `in.eps` is **not** the same file as `out.eps` or it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<scale>` argument in `set view`, this will magnify the plot without changing text size or title position.

In your case, because you use the `map` view, you need:

```
set view 180,0,1.5
```

where `180,0` is equivalent to `map` view and `1.5` is the scaling factor.

Comment: As a note: The upcoming 5.0 version has a `scale`, so that you can use `set pm3d map; set view scale 1.2`.